# downloading spring petclinic by installing tomcat 7 maven plugin from command line

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I am trying to download a fresh copy of the [java spring petclinic sample application](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/), but am having trouble getting it from the windows 7 command line because the tomcat7 plugin is not installed.  I therefore took the pom.xml syntax [from this page](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/tomcat7-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html), put the resulting pom.xml in the same directory as the command line was focused on, and typed the following into the command line:

mvn clean install tomcat7:run

But I got a long error message.  Can someone show me how to fix the pom.xml (and anything else) so that I can download the maven tomcat7 plugin to a stable location where maven will always know where it is?

Here is the pom.xml I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <build>
    <!-- To define the plugin version in your parent POM -->
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <!-- To use the plugin goals in your POM or parent POM -->
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Here is a screen shot of the error message:

[image]

---

EDIT:

---

Here is my updated pom.xml, which ran successfully, but left me without the ability to follow the next step in [these instructions](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <build>
    <!-- To define the plugin version in your parent POM -->
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <!-- To use the plugin goals in your POM or parent POM -->
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

So now how do I get the spring petclinic sample application to download?

Following [the instructions at this link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/), it is not available at either or the following addresses:

```
http://localhost:9966/petclinic/
http://localhost:8080/petclinic/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is exactly telling you what is wrong.

> 'modelVersion' is missing

Take a look at some example: [Introduction to the POM](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html). You just have to add `<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>` to the `project` element.

> Notice that modelVersion contains 4.0.0. That is currently the only supported POM version for both Maven 2 & 3, and is always required.

Usally the examples from plugin pages are only partial because you most likely already have a pom file and want to add the plugin. In the linked example this is indicated by `...`, so you can't copy a paste the whole thing.

Comment: So what do I put as values for the other elements of the minimum pom?  I just want the tomcat7 plugin to work with maven at the command line whenever I want it to work.  I want nothing else from this transaction.  There is no eclipse project.  The only reason this pom.xml exists is that I just want the plugin to work.  Here is the link I am using:  http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Minimal_POM

Comment: @CodeMed It doesn't really matter what the other values are, you have to come up with some name for the project. I'm not sure if I understand what you are actually trying to achieve though. The tomcat plugin seems to be already setup for the sample app. `mvn tomcat7:run` should work. Creating a new pom just for tomcat won't work, tomcat will be setup per project and not for the whole system (if that is what you are trying to do).

Comment: It should be available on `http://localhost:9966/petclinic/` if you just run the command in the sample app directory. The pom you posted will run tomcat, but it is another project that is otherwise empty - there is no code to compile/deploy. You don't need another pom, just the one provided by the sample app. If tomcat still doesn't run the problem probably is somewhere else.

Comment: I found the files for the petclinic application in the windows file explorer.  I am going to put it into eclipse and move on. +1 and credit for the answer.  Thank you very much for your help.